# Getting a apt-error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I am using 18.04 version.  i wanted to install game war zone 2100  so i installed its dependencies and after that i am getting this error.  i cannot update the software center is not opening .  the synaptic package manager is also not opening. On the status bar the red minus icon appears as a error. i even cant upgrade. the apt update gives me this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                 
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/popcorntime/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/popcorntime/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The value 'xenial' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Comment: Why do you have `trusty` (14.04) and `xenial` (16.04) PPAs in 18.04?

Comment: no didnt work out for me

Answer (score 0):

acctually i just pasted the dependencies list to download and install .  after the error i realised that the source was for 14.04 xenial .  so now i regret for my that move.i was installing the game  warzone 2100 3.3.0.